# Restart each loop every 4 items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UI which has 4 components in a row, with multiple rows, and the height of each component is variable based on content inside of it.

I would like for each component in the same row to have the same height, for that height to be set by the tallest component in the row, and for each row to be independent from every other row in terms of setting heights for the components within it.

The place where I am currently stuck is that if I don't break the loop, every component will take the height of the tallest component on the page, but if I break it at `index < 4` then every component will take the height of the tallest component in the first row.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/schrdr/6d50skwy/)

```js
var maxComponentHeight = -1;

$('.component').each(function() {
  var componentHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

  if ($(this).index() < 4) {
    if (componentHeight > maxComponentHeight) {
      maxComponentHeight = componentHeight;
    }
  } else {
    return false
  }
})

$('.button button').on('click', function() {
  $('.component').css('height', maxComponentHeight);
})
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.component {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.component:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
}

.component:nth-child(7) {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='button'>
  <button>
    align heights
  </button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer recalculating the desired heights inside a function after the button is clicked so I can set height for every 4 element not a preset height for all elements:

```js
function setHeight(){
  var maxComponentHeight = -1;
  var counter=0;
  var currentRow;

  $('.component').each(function() {
    var componentHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    counter++;
    if (componentHeight > maxComponentHeight) {
      maxComponentHeight = componentHeight;
    }
    
    if (counter==4){

        currentRow= Math.floor($(this).index()/4);
        
        //Selecting elements in same row 
        //by comparing the quotient against 4
        
        $('.component').filter(function(){
          if (Math.floor($(this).index()/4)==currentRow){
            return true;
          }
          else{
            return false;
          }
        }).css('height', maxComponentHeight);
        
        counter=0;
        maxComponentHeight = -1;
    }
  })
}

$('.button button').on('click', function() {
 setHeight();
})
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.component {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.component:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
}

.component:nth-child(7) {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='button'>
  <button>
    align heights
  </button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help here. I'm wondering if you have any suggestions on how to make this work if a row doesn't have 4 components, but only 2 or 3? I think this approach breaks if there are not 4 components in the row.

Comment: Yes. repeat the whole code inside the if block  `if(counter==4) ` again after the each loop was finished @schrdr

Answer (score 1):

all you need to collect the max height in each row then after you click you assign the new heights.

```js
var maxComponentHeight = -1;
var maxComponentHeightRow=[];
$('.component').each(function() {
  var componentHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    if (componentHeight > maxComponentHeight) {
      maxComponentHeight = componentHeight;
    }
       
      let index = Number($(this).index());
      if ( index % 4 === 3 ) {       
        maxComponentHeightRow.push(maxComponentHeight);
        maxComponentHeight=-1;
      } 
})


$('.button button').on('click', function() {
  let index = 0;
  $('.component').each(function() {
  $(this).css('height', maxComponentHeightRow[index]);
  //console.log(maxComponentHeightRow[index]);
    if (Number($(this).index()) % 4 === 3 ) {
      index ++;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.component {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.component:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
}

.component:nth-child(7) {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='button'>
  <button>
    align heights
  </button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help here. I'm wondering if you have any suggestions on how to make this work if a row doesn't have 4 components, but only 2 or 3? I think this approach breaks if there are not 4 components in the row.

Comment: just look to the js code 4 components: index % 4 === 3, and for 3 components then: index % 3 === 2, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you want to use javascript to calculate the height instead of css?

Here's some sample code which uses flex-box layouts to fill the space provided which sounds like what you wanted. Grid is also another good option if you want a fixed number of columns.

```css
.button {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.component {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.component:nth-child(2) {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.component:nth-child(7) {
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 component">
    component
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I should have been more clear in my original post - this is in a wordpress environment where a third party plugin renders the components for me. The content pieces inside are nested many levels deep, and I don't have much control over it. 

I think flex would be the ideal solution if it weren't so prohibitively difficult with the nested divs.